# Minizinc: generate a valid shift

Tags: arrays, minizinc

Hope someone can help me with this!

The original problem is to generate valid shifts like explained below:

I have arrays like this [m,m,m,o,o,l,l,m,m,m,l,m,m,m] with a fixed length (S) where m is work, o is office and l free. What I need to make sure is that at least every 6m I have two l together (ll). The o does not count as work or as free. Examples:

```
mmlmmlmmmll is not valid (7 ms without two ls)
mmlmmlmmll is valid
mmomomommll is valid
```

What I was trying is to create an array with 0 (for ls) and 1 (for ms) but removing from the array all the o and the non consecutive ls. So, for the above examples would be:

```
mmlmmlmmmll -> 111111100
mmlmmlmmll -> 11111100
mmomomommll -> 11111100
```

This way I could use a sliding_sum or at_least constraint to solve it. However, I cannot manage to create this new array as it would have a different size than the original (S). A valid option is to pad at the end with 0 the remaining slots until S.

Any help is appreciated

Edit. This is the code so far:

```
enum TypeOfShift = {l,m,o};
enum Staff = {John, Mike, Mary};
array[Staff, 1..30] of TypeOfShift: Roster=[|
m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  o,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  l|
l,  l,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  o,  o,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  m,  m|
m,  m,  l,  l,  m,  o,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  m|];
array[Staff, 1..30] of var 0..2: RosterCalculated = array2d(Staff, 1..30,[if (Roster[i,d]==l) then 0 else (if (Roster[i,d]==o) then 2 else 1 endif) endif | i in Staff, d in 1..30]);
output[if (d==1) then "\n\(i) " ++ " " ++ show(RosterCalculated[i,d]) ++ " " else show(RosterCalculated[i,d]) ++ " " endif | i in Staff, d in 1..30];
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the **code** of your current attempt?

Comment: is `llmmllmmllmm` valid? what about `llmmmmmm`? what about `mmmmmm`? If the position is important, then using `sliding_sum` may not be enough.

Comment: thanks for answer. We are talking about a size of 30 days, llmmllmmllmm is valid as ll breaks the cycle (like a reset). You have at least 2 ls after 6 (or less days). llmmmmmm is not valid unless is the end of the array, if it is not then you would need ll at the end. As I said, after 6 ms you need 2 ls. If you have 2ls after less than 6ms is still valid.

Comment: and the two `l` must always be contiguous, right? If there are non-contiguous `l` these must be ignored like the `o`?

Comment: exactly. If there are more than two contiguous l is fine as well. We keep them all

Comment: Original post edit with code. In the example, first two rosters are fine but the third one isn't

Answer (score 2):

This answer provides a **simple & effective** solution for the problem stated in the question, that is, *how to determine if a **given shift** is valid or not*. [Note that in this case it is not necessary *(actually, it is counterproductive)* to declare the content of any array as `var $T`].

---

One option is to:

- determine the starting position of all `ll` in the array (array `double_l_pos`)
- determine the position of each `o` in the array (array `has_o`)
- determine the cumulative number of `o` in the array from the beginning (array `cum_has_o`)
- fix the position of all `ll` so that it ignores any `o` preceding it (array `fixed_double_l_pos`)
- determine the distance between all `ll` starting positions (array `double_l_distance`)
- require that no distance value is larger than `6`

**Example:**

```
include "globals.mzn";

enum TypeOfShift = {l,m,o};
enum Staff = {John, Mike, Mary};

array[Staff, 1..30] of TypeOfShift: Roster=[|
    m,  m,  m,  l,  l, o,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  l|
    l,  l,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  o,  o,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  m,  m|
    m,  m,  l,  l,  m,  o,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  m|];

constraint forall (s in Staff)
(
    let {
        array[int] of TypeOfShift: shifts = [Roster[s, i] | i in 1..30];
        array[int] of int: double_l_pos = [ i - 1 | i in index_set(shifts) where
                                                    i > 1 /\
                                                    shifts[i-1] == l /\
                                                    shifts[i] == l];
        array[int] of int: has_o = [ if el == o then 1 else 0 endif | el in shifts ];
        array[int] of int: cum_has_o = [
                              sum ( j in index_set(shifts) where j <= i) ( has_o[j] )
                              | i in index_set(has_o) ];
        array[int] of int: fixed_double_l_pos = [ pos - cum_has_o[pos] | pos in double_l_pos ];
        array[int] of int: double_l_distance = [fixed_double_l_pos[1]] ++
            [fixed_double_l_pos[i] - fixed_double_l_pos[i-1] - 1 - 1
            | i in index_set(fixed_double_l_pos) where i > 1];
    } in
        forall(dist in double_l_distance) (
            dist <= 6
        )
);

solve satisfy;
```

Everything here is statically computed, so the model inconsistency can be detected even before the actual solving is started.

---

Addendum: since this is a **roster** problem, you may want to read in detail the [roster](https://github.com/MiniZinc/minizinc-benchmarks/tree/master/roster) and the [on-call-rostering](https://github.com/MiniZinc/minizinc-benchmarks/tree/master/on-call-rostering) models in the `MiniZinc` benchmarks repository. Those files may contain better approaches for dealing with your problem.

Comment: Great help!! Thanks so much. The Roster is actually a var but I didn´t want to complicate too much the question. There is however one caveat, when there is "lol", it is not like two consecutive ls... O's break the rest but it does no compute as work... Sorry I didn't explain myself correctly

Comment: @user12262184 fixed the answer. If the Roster is actually a `var`, then your problem is *"generate a valid shift*" rather than *"determine the validity of a shift"*. These are completely different problems, but your question it is phrased in a way that it asks for the latter rather than the former. You should open a new question with the **actual problem**, or edit your question to frame the real problem (in which case I will self-delete my answer).

Answer (score 1):

This new answer deals with the more general problem of **generating** a valid schedule. In this case we are dealing with **decision variables** so the other approach cannot be easily implemented.

My suggestion is to use the [**regular global constraint**](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.3.2/en/lib-globals.html#extensional-constraints-table-regular-etc) to deal with counting the number of `m` and `l`. This ensures that the provided solution does not place more than `6` sub-sequent `m` (ignoring `o` and single `l`) in a sequence.

**Example:**

```
include "globals.mzn";

enum TypeOfShift = {l,m,o};

% sat:
%array[1..30] of var TypeOfShift: shift = [m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  o,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  l];

% sat:
%array[1..30] of var TypeOfShift: shift = [l,  l,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  o,  o,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  m,  m];

% unsat: too many m
% array[1..30] of var TypeOfShift: shift = [m,  m,  l,  l,  m,  o,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  l,  m];

% unsat: o breaks double l
% array[1..30] of var TypeOfShift: shift = [l,  l,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  o,  o,  l,  l,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  o,  l,  m,  m,  m,  m,  m,  l,  l,  m,  m];

% free assignment
% [NOTE: this will give a trivial answer because of missing constraints]
array[1..30] of var TypeOfShift: shift;

%          |   1     2     3   <= Input Values
%          |   m     o     l
% ---------------------------- 
%  1 m0_l0 | m1_l0 m0_l0 m0_l1
%  2 m1_l0 | m2_l0 m1_l0 m1_l1
%  3 m2_l0 | m3_l0 m2_l0 m2_l1
%  4 m3_l0 | m4_l0 m3_l0 m3_l1
%  5 m4_l0 | m5_l0 m4_l0 m4_l1
%  6 m5_l0 | m6_l0 m5_l0 m5_l1
%  7 m6_l0 |   -   m6_l0 m6_l1
%  8 m0_l1 | m1_l0 m0_l0 m0_l0
%  9 m1_l1 | m2_l0 m1_l0 m0_l0
% 10 m2_l1 | m3_l0 m2_l0 m0_l0
% 11 m3_l1 | m4_l0 m3_l0 m0_l0
% 12 m4_l1 | m5_l0 m4_l0 m0_l0
% 13 m5_l1 | m6_l0 m5_l0 m0_l0
% 14 m6_l1 |   -   m6_l0 m0_l0
% ^
% states
array[1..14, 1..3] of 0..14: transition_relation =
    [|  2,  1,  8,  % m0_l0
     |  3,  2,  9,  % m1_l0
     |  4,  3, 10,  % m2_l0
     |  5,  4, 11,  % m3_l0
     |  6,  5, 12,  % m4_l0
     |  7,  6, 13,  % m5_l0
     |  0,  7, 14,  % m6_l0
     |  2,  1,  1,  % m0_l1
     |  3,  2,  1,  % m0_l2
     |  4,  3,  1,  % m0_l3
     |  5,  4,  1,  % m0_l4
     |  6,  5,  1,  % m0_l5
     |  7,  6,  1,  % m0_l6
     |  0,  7,  1,  % m0_l7
    |];

constraint regular(
    [ if s == m then 1 else
      if s == o then 2 else
                     3 endif
                       endif
      | s in shift],                % sequence of input values
    14,                             % number of states
    card(TypeOfShift),              % number of different input values of state machine
    transition_relation,            % transition relation
    1,                              % initial state
    1..14,                          % final states
 );

solve satisfy;
```

**Important Notes:**

- this can also be used to verify existing solutions;
- one should place the **regular** constraint within a **predicate**, so that it can be easily applied to all members of the Staff without code duplication;
- `MiniZinc` prints a **trivial answer** for this model only because there is no other constraint on the `shifts` array (i.e. *the minimum number of `m` required in a month*).

Comment: Thanks again. Great help again!